# Hiding Apply label retention column in SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, retention

I have created a retention policy label that applies to one of our SharePoint site collections. And every time the users want to make a new item in a list, the column appears in the new form. I have tried to hide/disable the column; however, I can't find the column in any location. The only place is showing it when the users want to create a new item.

Kind Regards [image]

Answer (score 0):

Per my knowledge and test, after applying retention policy label for a site collection, the Apply label column in the modern New form cannot be hidden.